# How to combine multiple try except block in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, try-except

I was reviewing existing code and I found this try except block. This code was part of the unit test code which was taking more time to execute. So I wanted to work on parts where I can efficiently write code to improve performance.

I have around 10 try except block in my code (pasted few lines of code below for better understanding). Is there a more Pythonic way to combine these try except block for better readability and performance improvement?

```
try:
    from X import *
except ImportError:
    from Y import *
try:
    from A import *
except ImportError:
    from B import *
try:
    from I import *
except ImportError:
    from J import *
```

Comment: Better from what perspective?

Comment: What do you find inadequate about this code?

Comment: This looks good. I know there are ways to do this, But I confidently say that the ways are not readable as your code.

Comment: you can have a dictionay where each key is the module you want to import and the value is the alternative import. then just iterate over each key, try to import it and in the except import the value of that key

Comment: If they do not condition each other, that's more or less the right way to code

Comment: So this is a question that should be migrated to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @kenntnisse such a post would not be accepted on CR as it is off-topic because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114). Also, the [authorship of the code is questionable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/120114). It does look like [it needs focus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and can be voted closed as such.

Comment: This seems a bit [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. You might want to read [Why is “Can someone help me?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/1575353) not an actual question? and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)